# I have a IP address with some open services. How could I contact the owner?

Tags: ip, log-files, connection, nmap, messaging

After having serious problems (DNS incident) I found out an IP address of a machine. Is it in any way possible to contact the owner without knowing anything else like email, domain name or website? I scanned it via nmap and found some services like:

```
21/tcp   open     ftp
22/tcp   open     ssh
53/tcp   open     domain
80/tcp   open     http
81/tcp   open     hosts2-ns
135/tcp  filtered msrpc
139/tcp  filtered netbios-ssn
445/tcp  filtered microsoft-ds
3306/tcp open     mysql
8081/tcp open     blackice-icecap
```

I thought on leaving something in one of the log via a ssh connection test or one of the other services or something like that.

How can I leave a message that is seen on such a system?

Warm regards

Comment: To make it clear, I want to leave MY contact informations.

Comment: How do you know they don't want those open? Those look like pretty reasonable services.

Comment: I don't care if they want them to be open. That is not my business. I just want to use them to contact them - sent my contact informations for another reason.

Comment: I just want to give the server/machine admin the possibility to reach out to me if they want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by asking [ARIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Registry_for_Internet_Numbers) using the WHOIS tool (it's in the upper right corner)

http://whois.arin.net/ui

They'll point you to the right affiliate ([APNIC](http://wq.apnic.net/apnic-bin/whois.pl/) or [RIPE](https://apps.db.ripe.net/search/query.html)) if it's not an American IP.  You'll either get the Company name (and maybe a Point of Contact, although those are usually outdated) that owns the IP or the name of the ISP hosting the site.  I've also found [SANS](https://isc.sans.edu/ipinfo.html) lookup tool useful to check if anyone else has noticed bad traffic on it.

Comment: It should be noted that SANS will give you the owner of the IP block, not necessarily an individual server.

Comment: Can you offer a method to directly contact the IP address owner?